# How to pass kendo multiselect values to contoller in asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have following code in controller.

```
 companyModel.lstusers = userBL.GetPayrollNotificationUsers();
 companyModel.emails = companyBL.getEmails();
```

This **lstusers** and **emails** are properties in model.

```
    public List<UserListModel> lstusers { get; set; }
    public List<EmailModel> emails { get; set; }
```

I have two kendo multiselect in view.

```
 @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
             .Name("lstusers")
             .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px" })
             .AutoClose(false)
             .Placeholder("Select User")
             .BindTo(new SelectList(Model.lstusers, "userId", "name"))
             .Value(new SelectList(Model.lstusers))
 )

 @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
          .Name("emails")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px" })
          .AutoClose(false)
          .Placeholder("Select emails")
          .BindTo(new SelectList(Model.emails, "EmailAddressId", "EmailAddress"))
          .Value(new SelectList(Model.emails))
 )
```

On post method I am passing this view to contoller.

```
  public ActionResult EditCompany(CompanyModel companyModel)
```

Now, I am getting null values in company Model for lstusers and emails.Can anyone help me out on this?

[Model Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDbUi.png)

Answer (score 1):

You need separate properties for your list and your selected items.. add 2 more properties to your model..

```
public List<UserListModel> lstusers { get; set; }
public List<EmailModel> emails { get; set; }
public string[] selectedUsers { get; set; }
public string[] selectedEmails { get; set; }
```

then use those names as the name of your multiselects

```
 @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
             .Name("selectedUsers")
             .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px" })
             .AutoClose(false)
             .Placeholder("Select User")
             .BindTo(new SelectList(Model.lstusers, "userId", "name"))
             .Value(new SelectList(Model.lstusers))
 )

 @(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
          .Name("selectedEmails")
          .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px" })
          .AutoClose(false)
          .Placeholder("Select emails")
          .BindTo(new SelectList(Model.emails, "EmailAddressId", "EmailAddress"))
          .Value(new SelectList(Model.emails))
 )
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MultiSelectFor` instead of the `MultiSelect` helper. The `MultiSelectFor` helper provide a component which is really bound to your property (get and set).

Example :

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelectFor(m => m.lstusers)
         .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "width:200px" })
         .AutoClose(false)
         .Placeholder("Select User")
         .BindTo(Model.YourDataSourceForUsersList)
```

Where `YourDataSourceForUsersList` represent a property of the model which contains all values that should be available in the multi select list.

Answer (score 0):

To add to answers already given, additionally, if your source list is a dynamic one based on search, you can do this:

```
@(Html.Kendo().MultiSelect()
.Name("emails")
.Placeholder("Email...")
.DataTextField("Text")
.DataValueField("Value")
.AutoBind(false)
.Value(Model.emails)
.HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "col form-control"})
.DataSource(source => {
     source.Read(read =>
     {
         read.Action("StaffEmail", "Home");
     })
     .ServerFiltering(true);
   })
 )
```

Example Home controller code:

```
public JsonResult StaffEmail(string text)
{
   using (var dbContext = new YourDBContext())
   {
      List<SelectListItem> staffEmail = new List<SelectListItem>();
      if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
      {
         staffEmail = YourResultsFromDB.Where(w => w.YourEmailProp.Contains(text)).
         Select(s => new SelectListItem
         {
            Text = s.eMail,
            Value = s.eMail
         }).ToList();                    
      }                
      return Json(staffEmail, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
}
```

Code which binds saved values to multiselect for eg. on edit view:

```
YourViewModel.emails = new SelectList(YourDataset.SelectedEmailsArr.Select(
s => new SelectListItem { Text = s, Value = s }).ToList();
```